# nav menu editing in child style.css turns off responsive menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress twentytwelve child theme.

the nav bar has a border-top that I would like to get rid of.

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-top: 0px solid #ededed;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

however when I add it to my child theme with 0px for the border,
the navigation refuses to flick over to the menu toggle when I scale down the window.

This is just weird and I'm at a loss to the reason why.

any help would be absolutely amazing.

Comment: can you post the link here?

Comment: Http://Www.thecleverhome.com/export

Comment: Also code was stripped from child style.css the original has border-top 1px

Comment: Bump! I've tried all day but nothing. Help!